# Spring Boot/MVC: How to serve static files outside JAR with special characters?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, static-files

I am currently working on a project where I need to serve static files residing on file system (outside the JAR-File).

What I currently have:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"some.package"})
public class MaboConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /* Irrelevant configs omitted */

    @Value("${application.pdfpath}")
    public String pdfPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
           .addResourceLocations("file:" + this.pdfPath);

        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
     }
}
```

This works for most files in the configured "pdfPath" directory. Now the problem is, that files containing special characters (like: "ä", "ö", "ü",...) cannot be found and the servers returns 404.

Example for working file (given pdfPath is /opt/tst/):

```
"/opt/tst/tstdir/with some space/01 - my tst pdf.pdf" -> is served under
"http://localhost:8100/contextRoot/files/tstdir/with some space/01 - my tst pdf.pdf"
```

Example for not working file:

```
"/opt/tst/tstdir/with some space/01 - my ätst pdf.pdf" -> should be served under
"http://localhost:8100/contextRoot/files/tstdir/with some space/01 - my ätst pdf.pdf"
```

I think this might be an encoding issue. The logs show that the incoming request is correctly URL-Encoded (UTF-8, e.g: "ä" becomes "%C3%A4"). Though, using trace, the logs also show that spring resolves "%C3%A4" to "?" when looking for the corresponding file.

Is there any way to tell the Resolver to resolve the File URL using a specific charset?

Comment: What happens if you try to request "http://localhost:8100/contextRoot/files/../../etc/passwd" ?
I don't know if there is built in protection for ["insecure direct object references"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference).
 Anyway, seems like you are trying to build a ftp server =D

Comment: What's your platform default encoding and locale? It's a bit odd that 2 UTF-8 bytes would resolve to `?`, as generally you have one byte charsets that end up giving `?` when trying to decode them to UTF-8. You'll need to pinpoint where things go wrong first, and then you can think about how to fix it.

Comment: Accessing files outside the context of the served directory is not possible. 
The server (linux) uses UTF-8 as default encoding. What's making this issue really strange is, if I put the files inside the jar (e.g. resources/static, which is a default location for spring too serve static files) it works without any problem. 

Oh and I'm not trying to built an ftp server. I'm building a SPA which gets data from a Spring Boot REST Service. This service is located inside a trusted zone and accesible through a reverse proxy. I need to be able to read the files inside the service.

Comment: And before someone asks, I cannot put the files inside the jar. I don't want to redeploy the service each time a pdf changed :)

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, did anyone find a solution to this?